# How to delay a function until another one executes in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, callback, promise

I am trying to write a simple registration function.  I keep getting tripped up while trying to verify whether or not a user email already exists.  I think that my issue has something to do with asynchronicity.  My intent is to hide the registration div and show the profile div once a 201 resonse is received from the server.  However, I believe my alert keeps coming up before the response is received.  How can I get the code to freeze until after my handlePost is finished?  I have tried it in the following ways:

## 1

```
registerButton.onclick = function(){
  var encodedBody = getRegistrationData();
  //if encodedbody then handlepost and show profile etc
  if (encodedBody) {
    var response = handlePost(encodedBody, 'user');
    if (response == '201') {
      hideRegistration();
      showProfile();
      showLoginNav();
      showLogin();
      // clearFields() need to create this
    } else {
      alert("Invalid password or email")
      console.log('hmm')
    }
  } else {
    alert("Invalid password or email")
  }
};
```

## 2

```
registerButton.onclick = function() {

  var a = function(callBack){
    var encodedBody = getRegistrationData()
    var response = handlePost(encodedBody, 'user')
    callBack(response)
  }

  var b = function(response) {
    if (response == '201') {
      hideRegistration();
      showProfile();
      showLoginNav();
      showLogin();
    } else {
      alert("Invalid password or email")
    }
  }
  a(b)
}
```

## 3

```
registerButton.onclick = function() {
  var encodedBody = getRegistrationData()
  if (encodedBody) {
    handlePost(encodedBody, 'user').then(function(response) {
      if (response == '201') {
        hideRegistration();
        showProfile();
        showLoginNav();
        showLogin();
      } else {
        alert("Invalid password or email")
      }
    })
  } else {
    alert("Invalid password or email")
  }
};
```

The following functions are used within the above:

```
function getRegistrationData() {
  var newUserEmail = document.querySelector("#newUserEmail");
  var newUserPassword = document.querySelector("#newUserPassword");
  var newUserPasswordVerify = document.querySelector('#newUserPasswordVerify');
  flag = []
  //verify passwords match
  if (newUserPassword.value != newUserPasswordVerify.value) {
    flag = false
    return flag
  } else {
    flag = true
  }
  //if user does not exist and passwords match return encoded body
  if (flag == true) {
    var encodedBody = 'email='+encodeURIComponent(newUserEmail.value)+'&'+'encryptedPassword='+encodeURIComponent(newUserPassword.value)
    return encodedBody
  }
};

function handlePost(encodedBody, flag) {
  if (flag =='user') {
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/users', {
      body: encodedBody,
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
      }
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response.status)
      return response.status
      // clearRegistrationFields();
      // function to get user profile data
    })

  }
};
```

Thanks in advance

Chris

Comment: Your snippet 3 should work, except that your function `handlePost` does not return anything. You should return the promise it creates. EG: `return fetch(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Your handlPost is asynchronous, so you should return a promise if you want to wait for the results:

```
function handlePost(encodedBody, flag) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (flag =='user') {
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/users', {
      body: encodedBody,
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
      }
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response.status)
      resolve(response.status)
      // clearRegistrationFields();
      // function to get user profile data
    })

  }
});
```

}

Now your snippet 3 will work, and the response object will be the 'response.status' resolved in the handlePost promise.

Note: you should also handle the promise failure. I'll leave you to work that out.